# Python MySQLdb: Is it possible to insert a cursor object without parsing it?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I need to do a daily load from a source db into a new db.

The new db table columns are identical structure to the source table select statement. The new db table is in a separate db so the cursor object is unique per db connection and I can't just do a `select into` query.

So, for example, if I do a select on some table in some source db:

```
# Assuming we already connected to the db and have a cursor object... 
sql_query = "SELECT val_bin, val_id, val_sel from table"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

I now have the objects I need in the `cursor` object from the select.

Then to insert, normally I would just grab each value and do an insert statement for each. For example:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    insert_query = "insert into new_table (val_bin, val_id, val_sel) VAULES (%s, %d, %s) % row[0], row[1], row[2]"
    destination_cursor.execute(insert_query)
    destination_db.commit()
```

However this seems tedious and slow to loop through everything. 
**Is there a way I can just insert the entire returned cursor object from the select statement into the new db table?** The destination table schema matches exactly with what returned from the select.

If it's not possible, that's fine I am just trying to make this easier and more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried `insert_query = "insert into new_table (val_bin, val_id, val_sel) VAULES (%s, %s, %s)"; destination_cursor.executemany(insert_query, cursor); destination_db.commit()`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `.executemany` instead of `.execute` if the goal to insert all the results from a given cursor into a table. The following is an illustration:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
destination_cursor = connection.cursor()
sql_query = "SELECT val_bin, val_id, val_sel from table"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
insert_query = "insert into new_table (val_bin, val_id, val_sel) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
destination_cursor.executemany(insert_query, cursor)
destination_db.commit()
```

I hope this proves useful.